# Lost, deactivated phone being used by someone on wifi. Can I track it?

Tags: lost-phone

The person who found my deactivated phone sent me a threatening E-mail from my own mailbox. He suggests he is has been reading my recent mail and says he found the phone in front of my house, suggesting he knows where I live. I have changed all my passwords so he won't get new mail but can access anything already downloaded.

Can I track this guy through the phone if he's using wifi or by IP address? He likely lives near me.

Comment: In what sense is the phone "deactivated"? Do you just mean that you told your carrier it's stolen so they've disconnected its SIM card?

Comment: Also, you'll find a lot of information in the tag wiki for the [tag:lost-phone] tag you've used, and the existing questions with that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if a) the phone is on
               b) wifi is on
               c) location is turned on (through settings)

As an experiment (using Android Device Manager through Google Dashboard) I tracked my phone with SIM card (cell towers) and with the card removed (WiFi). The wifi results were much more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If he can still access your email, you could send some url or image in a mail and check the ip or location from where its being accessed.

Comment: The questioner states that passwords have been changed so that new emails can't be accessed from the phone.

Comment: I got a new phone and was only usin my old phone as a music player. It is not an active phone but still works through wifi. I'm pretty sure GPS is off because it was a battery drain. That leaves IP address or wifi signal as a way to locate it. I wouldn't care about it if the person who has it wasn't being creepy and threatening.